# What is this yellow-white board?

Tags: kitchen-counters

In photo below, originally from [this video](https://youtu.be/nmiOiWL_EWc?t=75), is a dude working on a yellow-white board for a counter top.  What material is it?

[image]

Comment: Questions really need to be self-contained, so if the external reference ever disappears, the question still has validity.

Comment: @Tetsujin Updated accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be a foam-core backer board of unknown brand.  I believe it's similar to a popular brand called "Schluter" board of which there are several other brands/manufacturers.

Comment: Any idea why is it thicker for counter-top application than those usually used for walls?  For what purpose?

Comment: Probably, @caveman, because you don't set heavy pots on your walls.

Comment: @FreeMan - Any idea how much of strength does this add compared to a thinner one that has 1/3rd of this thickness?

Comment: it would be aboui 9 times stiffer

Comment: @Jasen - Interesting.  Any reasoning why strength increases quadratically as we increase thickness linearly?

Comment: That would be a good new question, @caveman. Though it might _possibly_ be a better fit at [physics.se].

Comment: basically this is because it increases the baseline for leverage and also increases the amount of material.